# Why is the modulus of a complex root of a "high" degree polynomial almost always very close to 1

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I plotted the solutions of some random polynomials of degree around 100 with integer coefficients in the range of -1000 to 1000.

ListPolarPlot[ Reverse /@ Map[{Abs[#], Arg[#]} &, Solve[Sum[RandomInteger[{-1000, 1000}] x^i, {i, 0, 100}] ==  0][[All, 1, 2]]], PolarAxes -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]}]

I was surprised to see that almost all the roots were very close to the unit circle.
Is there an easy explanation for this phenomenon.  Here, easy means I have yet to have a course in complex analysis.

Comment: It might not classify as "easy", but there is an article: [THE ZEROS OF RANDOM POLYNOMIALS CLUSTER UNIFORMLY NEAR THE UNIT CIRCLE](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/preprints/ni04017.pdf)

Comment: Here is another one: [On distribution of zeros of random polynomials in complex plane](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3517).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182412/why-do-roots-of-polynomials-tend-to-have-absolute-value-close-to-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results, including the proofs that their angles are uniformly distributed, can be found in [The zeros of random polynomials cluster uniformly near the unit circle](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/preprints/ni04017.pdf), C. P. Hughes and A. Nikeghbali, Compositio Math., 2008, with an history of the problem, and conditions on the polynomial coefficients.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if those results can be applied here. Are the conditions satisfied for the random polynomials from the question?